# Set default variables within MySQL functions if values are not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

when selecting a customers name from a table the database should call a function that formats the name to

> lastname, firstname

The function I created is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FORMAT_NAME`(firstname VARCHAR(25), lastname VARCHAR(25)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
RETURN CONCAT(lastname, ', ', firstname)
```

Within my SELECT I can now write

```
SELECT FORMAT_NAME(customer.firstname, customer.lastname) as Name
```

and this returns me

> Doe, John

**Normally I would solve this by code but I have to use a FUNCTION and have to set up default variables.**

How can I define default variables here if a value is empty or null or just not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the COALESCE function :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FORMAT_NAME`(firstname VARCHAR(25), 
    lastname VARCHAR(25)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
RETURN CONCAT(COALESCE(lastname, 'myDefaulValueName'), ', ', COALESCE(firstname, 'myDefaultValueFName'))
```